# Is it possible to create or edit a Jenkins Project on the fly?

Tags: jenkins

My question was too long so I've shortened it:

Is it possible to create or edit a Jenkins Project on the fly with a template/environment variables/coding/etc, and would this be possible via a trigger from Gitlab/hub/etc.? If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Your options are to use the [rest API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) (and there's more detailed information in your own Jenkins, check the link in the bottom right corner of every page), or to create the job directory structure and XML files manually and have Jenkins re-scan its workspace directories.

I strongly recommend the rest API.  It's designed for this sort of thing.

Comment: That's the way to do it! Thank you!